# Get Audio Video Images From SdCard Android Requires Minimum sdk 19

Tags: android, image, video

I Am Working In A Project Where I Have To get audio, video , images from SdCard and upload to server

I get The Images Quite Easily but Issue Is With The Audio And Video . Where `Cursor` Return `Null`
I Have Android lollipop .

This Is Code :-

```
Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null,null, null);
    int data_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
   int size_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_size");
   int name_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_display_name");
```

It Returns `null`

Now I am using This :-
https://limbaniandroid.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-when-select.html

But issue is, it requires minimum `SDK 19`, `Warning/error` in android studio .But it is compiling and running fine . I have **Android lollipop**
so its good to kept moving with this . Or I have to do my projects minimum `SDK 19`
Will it produce any error while uploading assigned .apk .
Because I have to upload it within 2, 3 days 
Or I have to write separate code for lower version 
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

Add the below file as `DocumentPathUtil.java`

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class DocumentPathUtil {

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context       The context.
     * @param uri           The Uri to query.
     * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static String getFileName(String path) {
        String fileNameSegments[] = path.split("/");
        return fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
    }
}
```

And in `onActivityResult` use:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_LOAD_DOC:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                String selectedImagePath = ImagePathUtil.getPath(this, data.getData());          
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

where `selectedImagePath` will give you the path to use.

`RESULT_LOAD_DOC` is the identifier used to check which data is being fetched.

Comment: Thanks For The Help .As I already said that i have already used this peace of code .the issue is DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri) requires minimun sdk 19 . And Android studio gives warning for set ur minimun sdk 19 . But It Compiles and runs fine on dvice  . if i continue with this . without setting my minimum sdk to 19 . Will it will create any issue . while creating assigned APK . For Uploading to play store .. will it works on lower version .Or Any Other Code Then That